# The most appropriate mongodb Version 4 in docker?

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker

I would like to use the MongoDb version 4 on my Linux server using Docker . 
But I don't know which tag is appropriate and stable ..
4.0 or 4.0.12 or 4.2.0 or ...

I've been using version 3.6  before and had no problem with it ... but since version 4 is better I want to use version 4 .

Thank you for saying which docker image I should use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get lost by the too many tags. If you take a closer look at their [digest](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo?tab=tags&page=1), you will notice that:

- `mongo:latest`
- `mongo:bionic`
- `mongo:4.2.0-bionic`
- `mongo:4.2.0`
- `mongo:4.2`
- `mongo:4.2-bionic`
- `mongo:4`
- `mongo:4-bionic`

all have the same (`6106df75f139`)

Also, from [MongoDB Versioning](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/versioning/):

> ## MongoDB Versioning
>
> **Important:** Always upgrade to the latest stable revision of your release series.
>
> MongoDB versioning has the form `X.Y.Z` where `X.Y` refers to either a release series or development series and `Z` refers to the revision/patch number.
>
> - If `Y` is even, `X.Y` refers to a release series; for example, `4.0` release series and `4.2` release series. Release series are **stable** and suitable for production.
> - If `Y` is odd, `X.Y` refers to a development series; for example, `4.1` development series and `4.3` development series. Development series are **for testing only and not for production**.